# "self as?" within protocol extension

Tags: swift, casting, protocol-extension

I was trying for casting "self" within protocol extension. It crashed with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when running on real device but worked well on simulator. What should I do to make this work? Thanks

My whole code:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {

}

protocol DataSetEditable {
    func add(_ data: Data)
}

extension DataSetEditable where Self: SomeClass {
    func add(_ data: Data) {
        print(data)
        if let someProtocol = self as? SomeProtocol {
            print(someProtocol)
            //do some extra works
        }
    }
}

class SomeClass: UIView {

}

class MyClass: SomeClass, DataSetEditable, SomeProtocol {
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myClass = MyClass()
        myClass.add(Data())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is likely a Swift bug since the compiler should have provided an error if it can't handle this. You should open it at [bugs.swift.com](https://bugs.swift.com). This feels related to [SR-544](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-544).

That said, as a rule it is very tricky to conform ObjC types to Swift-only protocols. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. This is a pretty complicated conformance, and clearly it doesn't always work. The solution is to expose the protocol to ObjC by adding `@objc`:

```
@objc protocol SomeProtocol: class {}
```

Comment: It work for me. I will report this bug, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extend the DataSetEditable like below.

```
extension DataSetEditable where Self: SomeClass & SomeProtocol {
  func add(_ data: Data) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Now the above extension method  `func add(_ data: Data)` only accessible to the subclass of `SomeClass` and follows `SomeProtocol`.

Comment: I cannot do that because I have AnotherClass which is a child of SomeClass and not conforming SomeProtocol protocol. So that AnotherClass cannot use add(_ data: Data) function and it has to implement add(_ data: Data) by itself.